# How do I prevent openCV from changing cameras?

Tags: python, opencv

I have a computer connected to two external cameras and am using the Python interface to openCV to do real-time video analysis for instrument control.  I love it.

But there is an odd quirk: the numbers assigned to the two cameras seem to be switching.  That is, my program will be working with the correct camera.  Then, if I run it again, there is a decent probability that it will grab the other camera.  To temporarily correct this I can toggle between the cameras by changing the integer in the command to initialize the camera:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

vs.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
```

or back again.  But, no matter which number I choose, there is still a chance that I'll get the wrong camera.  Do any of you have any ideas for how to choose the correct camera every time?